# Getting an InputStream of Writer using standard Java library

Tags: java, stream, inputstream, outputstream

I have an method which writes data to an OutputStream but needs to  return the contents of the OutputStream as an InputStream

```
public InputStream getInputStreamOfData(type param) {
    // ..... data 
    OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter();
    writer.write(data);
    // convert writer object to an InputStream 
}
```

I came across some libraries to do this such as IOUtils and other thread based methods. Is there a simple way to achieve this using standard Java library ? I want to return the contents in the writer as an InputStream to be consumed by the calling method.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Write to a `ByteArrayOutputStream`, then get the byte array, and return a `ByteArrayInputStream` from this byte array.

Comment: If the data is textual, he could also use StringWriter / StringReader, which would be slightly preferable.

Comment: Isn't this going to load the whole byte array in memory?

Answer (score 2):

I think the correct way to do it is using PipedInputStream. It's just like unix pipes (in highlevel). PipedInputStream constructor takes PipedOutputStream, so if you write to PipedOutputStream, you will get exactly what you want!

Good luck!

Comment: From the javadoc: *Typically, data is read from a PipedInputStream object by one thread and data is written to the corresponding PipedOutputStream by some other thread. Attempting to use both objects from a single thread is not recommended, as it may deadlock the thread*

Comment: Yes. That is one reason why I wanted to avoid using PipedInputStream